# Is it possible to access admin-ajax.php using PHP?

Tags: php, plugin-development, ajax

This might be a weird question, but I need to access `admin-ajax.php` using PHP.

One of my plugins creates a PDF that is displayed only in `admin-ajax.php`, I want to download this PDF using a piece of PHP code. Now I have already figured how to download a PDF and place it in the right folder, but when I try to reach `admin-ajax.php` inside my code it only returns "0".

I think this is because the PDF can only be reached by a logged-in user. So there is my question, is there anyway I can access `admin-ajax.php` using PHP?

Here is the code I am currently:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'so_payment_complete' );
    function so_payment_complete( $order_id ){
        // Static data for debugging
        $url     =   'https://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wcpn_export&request=get_labels&shipment_ids=124687111&_wpnonce=2da91e54ad';

    $arrContextOptions=array(
      "ssl"=>array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
      )
    );

    // Get the pdf data
    $pdf_data = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));

    if($pdf_data) :
      //Save PDF on server
      $pdf  = file_put_contents(__DIR__."/labels/$order_id.pdf", $pdf_data);

    else :

      print_r("Error!");

    endif;

}
```

Comment: are you doing this on a separate server? I don't see any code in your question

Comment: I am not doing it on a separate server, and the code seem pretty irrelevant for my question. I need a way to reach admin-ajax.php from PHP, but admin-ajax.php just returns 0. If I visit the URL while logged in, it returns the PDF, but when I am not logged in, the URL returns 0. So personally, I think I need a way to 'login' in my PHP code, but I have no idea how to do that on WordPress.

Comment: I ask for the code because it would let me tell you what you need to change to make it work, and it would also answer a tonne of questions avoiding me asking them in comments. There's also no information about the request you're sending to `admin-ajax.php`. What you've told me so far is that you have succesfully made  a request to that file, but no handlers matched your request and it fell back to the default handler which returns `0`, but I can't tell why as I can't see an example of the full URL you're using that has all the parameters, the code for the AJAX handler, or the PHP file

Comment: And yes, it's possible to interact with that file from another PHP file, but that's not going to help you solve your problem unless you can share specifics. E.g. are you including an `action` parameter? What parameters are there? If I knew the code for the handler it's possible there's a 1 liner that would let you use it without a login but I can't be sure without seeing, and I wouldn't know what the second part of that line would look like without it. Trust me when I say it is incredibly relevant.

Comment: Also if this were the REST API, you could make use of an application password, if the plugin you're interacting with has a REST API endpoint instead that would let you do this while logged in

Comment: I would like to already thank you for the help you have offered. I just added a code snippet to my original post. Just for a little more information, "example.com" is the URL of my current website, not an external website. If I got to the $url while logged in, it shows me the PDF, but if I do it while logged out it show a 0. Again, that is where I think the problem is hiding.

Comment: ok so the nonce in particular may be an issue as nonces expire, I take it wcpn stands for WooCommerce PostNL? It looks like this is where the logged in AJAX handler is https://github.com/postnl/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/admin/class-wcpn-export.php#L100 in theory if you had that object you could add the action with `wp_ajax_nopriv` instead of `wp_ajax_` and it would start working without a login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns a `0` because that AJAX handler is only meant for logged in requests, and no non_priv handler was registered. `0` is the final fallback.

### Attempt #1

While you could register your own AJAX handler that calls the function that generates the PDF and put it in a mini plugin, there's an alternative:

```php
add_action("wp_ajax_no_priv_wcpn_export", function() {
    do_action( "wp_ajax_wcpn_export" );
} );
```

The code at the other end may not like this as it might be relying on the user being logged in, or maybe it doesn't check, either way this will trigger the logged in handler for that AJAX when the logged out is requested. A simple workaround.

This leads to the next problem:

https://github.com/postnl/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/admin/class-wcpn-export.php#L232-L254

PostNL performs a number of checks, that you're logged in, that the nonce is valid, that the logged in user has the appropriate access rights, etc.

### Attempt #2

Lets use inheritance! Lets create a new class, lets call it `Martin_Export`:

```php
class Martin_Export extends WPCN_Export {
...
}
```

Our class will do 2 things and only 2 things.

First it will have a brand new `export` function. We'll copy paste the one from WCPN and remove those checks at the top. We won't copy paste anything else, just the `export` function.

Second, I'd recommend adding a new check for security, lets say a password parameter with a secret value only your PHP file knows. E.g. `if ( $_GET['foo'] !== 'bar' ) { wp_die('get outta here'); }`

Then, we have a line at the end after the class or somewhere else that hooks the new version of `export` into `admin-ajax.php` for logged out users like this:

```php
$martin_export = new Martin_Export();
add_action("wp_ajax_no_priv_wcpn_export", [ $martin_export, 'export' ] );
```

Now when you make an AJAX request and you aren't logged in, it'll run your slightly tweaked version instead. Just remember to add the secret parameter we added to your PHP script